# Does Shredder work with Stock damage?

Tags: xcom-2

The Shredder ability causes damage to weaken an enemy's armor.  Stocks ensure that if you miss, you cause damage.

If you miss, and the Stock does damage, does this then cause the Shredder effect?

Comment: According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/45279h/heres_how_weapon_accuracy_and_damage_works/czun87r), stocks just apply damage without any special bonuses (i.e. no, it doesn't shred), but I haven't seen anyone show evidence for this in the code itself, it's just anecdotal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Damage from stocks is applied without regard to armor (e.g., a Superior Stock does 3 damage directly to HP, bypassing all armor). Accordingly they will not shred armor.

<sub>Source: I've brought a Grenadier with Shredder and a stock equipped to dozens of missions.</sub>

Comment: Stock damage definitely *does* take armor into account. I've definitely had folks with a superior stock do 1 damage to shieldbearers on a miss.

Comment: @SableDreamer It takes shields into account, but shields are not armor. Are you referring to shields?

Comment: Have you had a stock that does more than 1 damage equipped on a grenadier, to confirm it does full damage? I'm not sure I have, but I can confirm that no shredding occurs, either way.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Nope. Armor. Unless you're running some mod that adds a pierce effect to the stock, stock damage should be reduced by armor. (As far as I've experienced)

Comment: I agree - stock damage seems to go down by armor for me as well.

Comment: This isn't my experience at all, but I'll have to double check. In the meantime I encourage anyone who is seeing different results to post an answer to that effect.

Comment: @Aurelius: I'm pretty sure my dude with skulljack has no stock and does 2 damage on a miss anyway. Are you sure its the stock that is doing that (I'll admit I may be wrong about having stock but I'm pretty sure I've not got a stock on any guns).

Comment: Just got around to checking. Can confirm that my specialist doesn't have a stock on his gun.

Comment: Skulljack is a red herring; always does 2 damage on miss, unaffected by Stock (also gives extra action).  

Stock damage can be decreased by armor (minimum 1), but does not shred.